# An explicit value for the identity column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to make a backup for my data from my first table DocumentManagement.tbDocumentsHistory and save it on DocumentManagement.tbDocuments

and because the DocumentManagement.tbDocuments have ID IDENTITY_INSERT column this error will raised

> An explicit value for the identity column in table 'DocumentManagement.tbDocuments' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

when i used this code

```
DELETE FROM DocumentManagement.tbDocumentsHistory
OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO DocumentManagement.tbDocuments 
FROM    DocumentManagement.tbDocumentsHistory
WHERE   DocumentID=@DocumentID
```

I tried to turn off the IDENTITY_INSERT on DocumentManagement.tbDocuments using this code

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT DocumentManagement.tbDocuments ON 
        DELETE FROM DocumentManagement.tbDocumentsHistory
            OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO DocumentManagement.tbDocuments 
            FROM    DocumentManagement.tbDocumentsHistory
        WHERE   DocumentID=@DocumentID
        SET IDENTITY_INSERT DocumentManagement.tbDocuments OFF
```

and I am still facing the same error!

my tables desc :

```
CREATE TABLE [DocumentManagement].[tbDocuments](
[DocumentID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[DocumentNameEn] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[DocumentNameAr] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[DocumentDescriptionEn] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[DocumentDescriptionAr] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[CreatedOn] [datetime2](7) NULL,
[ModifiedOn] [datetime2](7) NULL,
[AddedBy] [bigint] NULL,
[modifaiedBy] [bigint] NULL,
[PhysicalName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Extension] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
[DocumentTypeID] [bigint] NULL,
[PhysicalPath] [nvarchar](max) NULL,


CONSTRAINT [PK_tbDocuments] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([DocumentID] ASC)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

) ON [PRIMARY]

```
CREATE TABLE [DocumentManagement].[tbDocumentsHistory](
[DocumentID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[DocumentNameEn] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[DocumentNameAr] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[DocumentDescriptionEn] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[DocumentDescriptionAr] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[CreatedOn] [datetime2](7) NULL,
[ModifiedOn] [datetime2](7) NULL,
[AddedBy] [bigint] NULL,
[modifaiedBy] [bigint] NULL,
[PhysicalName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Extension] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
[DocumentTypeID] [bigint] NULL,
[PhysicalPath] [nvarchar](max) NULL, CONSTRAINT [PK_tbDocumentsHistory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([DocumentID] ASC)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: nvarchar(max) for a document name. Seriously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will solve the problem but I was trying to make it better using the OUTPUT

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT DocumentManagement.tbDocuments ON
        INSERT INTO DocumentManagement.tbDocuments
                ( DocumentID, DocumentNameEn , DocumentNameAr , DocumentDescriptionEn ,
                  DocumentDescriptionAr , CreatedOn , ModifiedOn ,
                  AddedBy , modifaiedBy , PhysicalName ,Extension ,
                  DocumentTypeID ,PhysicalPath
                )   
        SELECT * FROM  DocumentManagement.tbDocumentsHistory
        SET IDENTITY_INSERT DocumentManagement.tbDocuments OFF

        DELETE FROM DocumentManagement.tbDocumentsHistory           
        FROM    DocumentManagement.tbDocumentsHistory
        WHERE   DocumentID=@DocumentID
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to modify your INSERT-statement and add a column list containing the name of the identity column for this to work.

Any INSERT-statement using an identity insert needs a columns list, like in this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tab 
(
   ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
   Name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Tab ON
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Tab (ID, Name) VALUES (3000, 'Groucho')
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Tab OFF
```

Comment: I did not understand exactly your point ,can you clarify it please .

Comment: Dont use * for insert, state the column names explicitly

Comment: @KAJ: i think the link you posted states id does.

Comment: Okay , I did try this SET IDENTITY_INSERT DocumentManagement.tbDocuments OFF

Comment: Your syntax for set identity insert is correct as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx. Explicitly state the columns from DELETED that you want to insert into the other table. If that doesn't work try doing a test insert into the table with set identity insert on separate to your query just to prove there isn't a different issue

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** The column list specification that the error is requesting is the column list of the destination table. In this case, `OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO DestinationTable (IdentityColumn, othercolumn, anothercolumn,...)`, it won't work if you just explicitly indicate the columns from the source data instead of doing `Deleted.*`.

The error message states that you have to turn on identity insert **and specify a column list**. The problem lies in the fact that you have not specified a column list for your insert.

You can check out the [output clause documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to see how you indicate a column list there. In this case, taking into account the columns on your own accepted answer, your sql code would look something like:

```
DELETE FROM DocumentManagement.tbDocumentsHistory
OUTPUT DELETED.DocumentID, DELETED.DocumentNameEn, Deleted.DocumentNameAr,
Deleted.DocumentDescriptionEn, Deleted.DocumentDescriptionAr, Deleted.CreatedOn, 
Deleted.ModifiedOn, Deleted.AddedBy, Deleted.modifaiedBy, Deleted.PhysicalName, 
Deleted.Extension, Deleted.DocumentTypeID, Deleted.PhysicalPath  INTO DocumentManagement.tbDocuments
( 
                  DocumentID, DocumentNameEn , DocumentNameAr , DocumentDescriptionEn ,
                  DocumentDescriptionAr , CreatedOn , ModifiedOn ,
                  AddedBy , modifaiedBy , PhysicalName ,Extension ,
                  DocumentTypeID ,PhysicalPath
)
FROM    DocumentManagement.tbDocumentsHistory
WHERE   DocumentID=@DocumentID
```